# SetImageUri showing no Image

Tags: java, android

I want to let a image on my phone to show up in the Imageview. But in the ANdroid Studio emulator it is working but not on my own phone.

```
String imgPath = getIntent().getExtras().getString("imgPath");
    System.out.println(imgPath);


    if(!imgPath.equals("?"))
    {
        File img_file = new File(imgPath);
        ImageView imgView = findViewById(R.id.show_image_war);
        imgView.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(img_file));
    }
```

The path is /storage/emulated/0/imagesWarranty/img_MyWarranty_ID1.jpg . Both on the image in my phone and the path in my code where I get the image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might be issue of resolution. Even I was getting error of resolution while I was displaying image from uri.

I used below code and It worked for me :

```
Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(imagePath);
                        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(new File(imageUri.getPath()).getAbsolutePath(), options);
                        int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
                        int imageWidth = options.outWidth;
                        if (imageHeight > 4096 || imageWidth > 4096) {
                            BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                            opts.inSampleSize = 4;
                            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageUri.toString(), opts);
                            viewHolder.imgAvatarLogoList3.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                        } else {
                            Picasso.with(context)
                                    .load(new File(imageUri.getPath())) // Uri of the picture
                                    .into(viewHolder.imgAvatarLogoList3);
                        }
```

Comment: Thank you! But this flips the image 90 degrees.

Answer (score 0):

Addition to this answer [https://stackoverflow.com/a/48354307/9255006]
In that rotation bug define the image orientation for the image using ExifInterface.

Here is the code

```
private void SetOrientation(){

    try {
        ExifInterface exif=new ExifInterface(photoURI.getPath());
        int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);

        if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90) { orientationInDegrees=90; }
        else if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180) { orientationInDegrees=180; }
        else if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270) { orientationInDegrees=270; }
        else { orientationInDegrees=0; }

        Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(orientationInDegrees), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

You can then set this orientation to your image.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the image has a very high resolution that the system needs some additional milliseconds to display, and since this happens in the UI thread `onDraw()` of the image view will draw it as an empty.
The easiest way I found for this issue is to use the Picasso library this way:

```
Picasso.get().load(imgUri).fit().centerCrop()
```

.into(imageview);

The reason behind those two methods (`fit()`, `centerCrop()`)
Is that fit make sure that the image fit the bound container and then crop the image which force the system to redraw the image but this time with the convenient resolution (because of fit and crop).

Comment: Thanks Chris!. My laptop was far, and I was using my phone's keyboard .